# Any Way to Mute Chrome Tabs, Without Showing Mute Icon?

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I just published my first public Chrome extension. It's called Silent Site and it allows you to whitelist / blacklist sites fom playing audio. My extension effectively uses the tabs API to mute tabs by using the chrome.tabs.update and changing "muted" to true or false.

However, I have gotten some feedback from users asking if I could make the tabs mute without having that little muted speaker icon appearing on the right side of each tab. That sounds impossible, but I thought I'd ask. Is there any way to mute a tab without having Chrome browser show the icon in the tab?

Comment: I think it is useful to un-mute. Don't think this will ever be supported.

Comment: I didn't think so, but had to ask.